# NotificationSendingSplitViewcontroller, what is it for?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

In debugging a test iOS app in SwiftUI I've seen a controller I am not sure I understand. Why is it there? What is its role?

```
NotificationSendingSplitViewcontroller
```

[image]

Can anybody explain what that ViewController is doing?

Comment: Probably it's some internal view controller which gets added automatically, I couldn't find any documentation or relevant information so far. I'm also curious now :)

Comment: Guys... investigating View Debug mode you can find very very many interesting things, but that completely does not mean that you could use those... probably ever. )) It's reverse-engineering of Apple's private things ))